# Numbers/letters following @ of file (gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab

What are the numbers/letters after this @:

`public @ 6fa07654`

I'm in the files and they don't seem to point to any commits. Furthermore, It's a folder and there should be some files in it, but when I click on it, it seems to just redirect me to the same spot

Answer (score 1):

Note that the SHA-1 sum may not represent a commit, it may also represent a tree, blob, or TAG.  Don't assume it's a commit that will appear in git log.

SHA-1 sum - a hash representing the tree of files (and dirs) in your repository.  The hash is composed of the file listings of each dir and every file's contents.  You change a dir or file and this sum will change.  Also, the commit SHA-1 sum will change based on the timestamp of the commit - meaning if you cherry-pick or rebase an already-committed commit, it will get replayed and re-committed, so its timestamp, and therefore its SHA-1 sum, will change.

try this:

```
git rev-parse 6fa07654
```

take the output of that and find out what it is:

```
git cat-file -t <output> // get the type of the object
git cat-file -p <output> // get the contents of the object
```

Comment: gives me a `fatal: ambiguous argument '6fa07654': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
`

Comment: some possible solutions: 1) I am completely wrong 2) the commit no longer exists - maybe history was rewritten and the object was garbage collected (unlikely), 3) maybe the 8 characters are not enough to uniquely identify the object (also unlikely) - you can do an "ls <root of your repo>/.git/objects/6f" and if 6f isn't a real folder, or if you don't find a file in there like "a07654..." then I'm not sure...

Comment: if #3 fails, then it's also possible the commit you're looking for is a commit in someone else's branch that u dont have

Comment: Well the public folder was from `create-react-app` so I'm not sure... And yeah don't seem to find the other two things you mentioned